# Estoy haciendo la validación de un campo en HTML al cual le quiero añadir una longitud mínima y máxima de caracteres y no lo consigo de ninguna manera

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo la validación de un campo en HTML al cual le quiero añadir una longitud mínima y máxima de caracteres y no lo consigo de ninguna manera. Esta es la ultima posición en la que he probado, pero en todas las posiciones me da error de sintaxis.

```
<div class="input-row">
          <label class="min-width-label" for="name"> Nombre </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ramón" required pattern="^[A-ZÑa-zñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ'° ]{3,20}+$">
```

Comment: El "+" representa "una o más veces". ¿Estás seguro de que ese "+" va en esa expresión regular? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema radica en los caracteres de inicio y fin de expresión regular. Si entendi bien tu pregunta, creo que la solucion seria ponerlo asi:

```
<div class="input-row">
          <label class="min-width-label" for="name"> Nombre </label>
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ramón" required pattern="[A-ZÑa-zñáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ'° ]{3,20}">
```

Comment: De hecho, también funciona con `^`  y `$`. Solo basta con remover `+`.